# Unlisted/uncredited voice "Khalaid"(?) in S01E07 of Gary and his Demons

Tags: casting, voice-acting, gary-and-his-demons

The voice of the "trickster demon" Khalaid or (Calade or how ever [*kɑlɘid*] is spelled) reminds me of one of the main guys from Picnicface, particularly as the Genie in "Gun Genie":

IMDB doesn't list that character, as don't the episode credits:
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8542252/reference

Does anybody know who voiced that character or how to find that information?

Answer (score 1):

Upon my research, I looked up who the actor from Picnicface is, and... Sure enough, he (Mark Little) **is** the voice of "Gary", the main character of *Gary and his Demons*:

https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3283711/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1

...and I guess it's fair to say that, although not credited, he and/or other cast members will probably voice other characters on the show, and it's therefore highly likely that it is really him giving the *Trickster Demon* his voice